# Deploy Node.js socket.io project on shared OVH server

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm trying to **build and deploy** my app to **OVH** server, my client doesn't want a cloud solution, he want to host it or deploy it on OVH (they told me OVH support Node.js) and to be honest i have no idea how to do it.

my project work fine in development, its a Real-time chat with **socket.io** and **MySql** and some package as **knex**, in front-end i worked with **React.js** ( which i have no problem with it right now )

I can provide more informations if needed. thx a lot

```
const app = require("express")();
var cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const mysql = require("mysql");

const knex = require("knex")({
  client: "mysql",
  connection: {
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "chat_message",
  },
});


const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    credentials: true,
  },
});

app.get("/messages", function (request, result) {
    knex
      .select()
      .table("messages")
      .then((data) => result.send(data))
  });

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("messageClient", (sms) => {
    
    knex("messages")
      .insert({
        message: sms.msg,
        socket_id: sms.id,
        dateMsg: sms.Temps,
        ip: sms.ip,
        name: sms.name,
      })
      .then((e) => console.log("data insert succees"));
      socket.broadcast.emit("messageAll", sms);
  });
});
server.listen(5000, () => console.log("Port: 5000"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OVH is a private company and I'm not sure if [this would be offtopic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions) and more suitable to ask their own support. However you should know that shared hosting in general does not support long running processes like nodejs. They only support PHP on the server.